# How I can get email content before send it in prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, email, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I work On a prestashop module , I want to get the email content before the prestashop send it, I try but I get a empty var 
this the function that send the mail with template

```
quotesMailConfirm(
    'quotes_notify',
    $to,
    $tpl_message_vars,
    $this->module->l('Administrator offer', 'adminquotescontroller'),
    _PS_MODULE_DIR_ . $this->module->name . '/mails/',
    $this->context->language->id,
    $this->context->shop->id
);
```

This is my attempt:

```
$template_html = '';
$template_txt = '';
$id_lang =  $this->context->cart->id_lang;
$iso = $this->context->language->iso_code;
$iso_template = $iso.'/quotes_notify';
// $template_path = $theme_path.'modules/'.$module_name.'/mails/';
$template_path = PS_MODULE_DIR_ . $this->module->name . '/mails/';
Hook::exec('actionEmailAddBeforeContent', array(
    'template' => quotes_notify,
    'template_html' => &$template_html,
    'template_txt' => &$template_txt,
    'id_lang' => 1
    ), null, true);
$template_html .= Tools::file_get_contents($template_path.$iso_template.'.html');

print_r($template_html);
die();
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: to convert it pdf